# Tapestry + JaxB conflict

Tags: tomcat, jaxb, conflict, tapestry

I need your help to resolve a conflict between Tapestry and JaxB.
The error is :

> com.sun.xml.stream.ZephyrParserFactory
>   cannot be cast to
>   org.codehaus.stax2.XMLInputFactory2

I find a way to resolve it, but it is for jetty : http://tynamo.org/tapestry-resteasy+guide

The solution seems to be to add a system properties to declare :

> javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory = com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory

But i don't know how to do this for Tomcat. I try to do it int he web.xml like :

```
<env-entry>
     <env-entry-name>
      javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
     </env-entry-name>
     <env-entry-value>
      com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory
     </env-entry-value>
     <env-entry-type>
      com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory
     </env-entry-type>
    </env-entry>
```

without success...

I am also aware for another solution :)

thx for helping me.

Comment: -Djavax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory in the JVM arguments works. Now i need to integrate it inside the war, like in the web.xml

Comment: You can't put system properties in a WAR, they're JVM-wide settings

Comment: Looks like the Tapestry developers reckon it's a good idea to couple Tapestry to a specific implementation of the StAX API (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-745). Great work, fellas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<env-entry>` properties are accessible via JNDI, and not as system properties, so that won't work. System properties must be specified on the command line when starting the Java VM.

How do you start your tomcat? If it is from the command line, try adding this snippet to JAVA_OPTS:

```
java -Djavax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory [...]
```

You should be able to do that either as an environment variable (Unix: `export JAVA_OPTS='-Djavax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory'`, Windows: `SET JAVA_OPTS='-Djavax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory'`) or in the Tomcat startup script itself (catalina.sh/catalina.bat).

If you start Tomcat from Eclipse, you can add the parameter via Debug Configurations | JRE | VM Arguments. Just paste `-Djavax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory` and you're good.

*Edit based on comment:* AFAIK, you cannot specify system properties in web.xml, sorry.

*An idea:* You can set system properties programmatically. Maybe you could add a call to System.setProperty() in your Tapestry application module. It will have to be executed before JAXB initializes.

Comment: Just thinking about this solution, and it works !
Thx a lot :)